# Laravel 5.3 - TokenMismatchException on every post request

Tags: laravel

I was working on my project normally and when i hit refresh to see a change that i just made in one of the html pages, the page showed a text on top left "Redirecting to: http://localhost:8888/xxx ". It redirected me to the login page. When i clicked login, the 'TokenMismatchException' error showed: [image]

The login form has the hidden input _token , header has it too. As i said everything was fine. I have been working on this project for 2 months. Is this related to files permissions ?

Here is the login form.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">

                    {{ csrf_field() }}

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                     <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Login
                            </button>
                            <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ url('/password/reset') }}">
                                Forgot Your Password?
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </form>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: How do you output the hidden input _token?

Comment: My input token is generated like this: "<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="dfoR9Y6Kfqo93P5v6lUL9tOeGVpjxLkOCxlbzeQ1">"

Comment: Like how do you output that? Do you use ```{{ csrf_field() }}```?

Comment: Yes i am using {{ csrf_field() }}

Comment: Did you check the error logs? Did you see anything weird there?

Comment: Where is the code for login ?? Without having a look at the code, we are helpless. And I guess `{{ csrf_field() }}` just prints the code in the browser window. Instead, what you need to do there is `{!! csrf_field() !!}`

Comment: The csrf field is fine. I have checked also other pages and for every post the tokenmismatch error shows. All this pages where fine. Unexpectedly now they dont work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After i installed a fresh laravel copy i started to paste my old files to see where would regenerate the mismatch token problem. 
It went down to the routes/web.php file. Something there was causing the error. **It was a space before the opening tag of php on routes/web.php file.** 
Something that did not caught my eye. Like that the project was working fine but suddenly did not anymore.

As i read , the space is considered an output. Check this explanation : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4345822/6634389

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use {{ csrf_field() }} or try with that?

Comment: Yes, i am using {{ csrf_field() }} on the login form.

Answer (score 2):

Run:

```
php artisan cache:clear; composer dump-autoload; composer clear-cache
```

Refresh the browser, make sure you generated the key for your app. This should work. For me it did.

Comment: generate another key with php artisan key:generate , close and open the browser, shutdown the server and turn it on again. But I really think the reason are your cookies, clear your browser cache/cookies and try again.

Comment: I cleared the cache/cookies , shutdown the server , key generate. Still no result. I ask ,what might be that none of post request work ? when they were working before. I am using mamp on mac. Anything i should look there ?

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/csrf-token-verify-error?page=1  and https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/tokenmismatchexception-on-ajax-call should help you out. I'm out of ideas honestly :/ clearing the cookies worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You are refreshing your page, so each time the pages load with same csrf-token. So when you are trying to post your data, laravel refuses it and provide error message due to each request should have a unique csrf-token. You can read about this here[laravekl csrf protection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf)

Either you should again reload your page or you should disable the csrf protection by commenting it inside the

> App=>Http=>Kernel.php

inside the $middlewareGroups=>'web'

```
 \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,   //comment this line
```

Comment: if i disable the VerifyCsrfToken , on every post request the website shows : "Redirecting to http://localhost:8888/xxx/ " and redirects to the page where i made the post.

Comment: check your form action url and where are you redirecting in the action in your controller

Comment: the action url and redirect in controller are fine. Has got something to do with posts in general. is not the fault of only one form post request.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, I solved it by using following in my view

`<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ session()->getToken() }}">`